# mssql execute: return both promise and recordsets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, promise, request-promise

I am using `node-mssql` to perform a bunch of operations inside a transaction. Spcifically, the methods used in order are `begin tran`,`bulk`,`bulk`,`exec`,`commit`. Here is part of the code, which works as-is:

```
// bulk insert #columns
.then(result => {  
    const request=new sql.Request(globalTx);
    const tableObj = new sql.Table('#columns');  //#columns
    /* some code to build the desired tableObj*/
    return request.bulk(tableObj);
})

// exec proc
.then(result => { 
    returnObject.lastSuccessfulStep='bulk #data'
    returnObject["#columns rows"]=result.rowsAffected
    const request=new sql.Request(globalTx);
    /* some code to build the desired proc call*/
    return request.execute('spc_sqlDMLCommand');
})

//commit
.then(result => { 
    return globalTx.commit(); // returns promise
})
```

So you can see the use of chained `.then`s. There is a `catch()` at the end.

My problem is that in the case od the `execute` method, while the `then() /catch()` promise structure feels friendly to me, I also need the information that the method returns through its callback. Citing the reference about the second parameter:

> callback(err, recordsets, returnValue) - A callback which is called
> after execution has completed, or an error has occurred. returnValue
> is also accessible as property of recordsets. Optional. If omitted,
> returns Promise.

**Is there a way to save err/recordsets/returnValue to some objects while still maintaining the flow, ie not having to cut-paste the subsequent `then()`s into the `execute`'s callback?**

Solution attempt:

I tried using a callback:

```
request.execute('spc_sqlDMLCommand',function cb(a,b,c){
    console.log('a:\n',a,'b:\n',b,'c:\n',c)
});
```

but I got this error:

> message: 'Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the
> SentClientRequest state', code: 'EINVALIDSTATE'

Following this up on the internet, it seems to be about multiple queries having problems. But, it already works for me if I do it in the way mentioned above...